# Mule originalFilename is null

Tags: java, mule, mule-el

I am creating a process using Mule 3.4.1 which after processing a file it writes out the file with a specific filename. 
The input filename is:     MMDDYYYY_sys_newhires.csv
The processed filename is: MMDDYYYY_sys_newhires_NNN.csv

The code that i am using is below:

```
#[filename = message.inboundProperties.originalFilename;
  filename= com.cfa.apps.icims.mule.CounterSingleton.getInstance().getCount() 
         +  filename.substring(0,filename.length() -1 -4) + ".csv";
  filename]
```

The problem exists in the first line. message.inboundProperties.originalFilename.

I have tried a number of different combinations

```
message.inboundProperties.originalFilename
message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']
message.inboundProperties.originalFileName
message.inboundProperties['originalFileName']
message.inboundProperties.sourceFilename
message.inboundProperties['sourceFilename']
message.inboundProperties.sourceFileName
message.inboundProperties['sourceFileName']
```

Now I have also tried nesting the #[header:originalFilename], this works by itself, but you can't nest the expression within the code at least as far as I know.

Any help?

**UPDATE:** I am using the inbound file transport

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you don't show the endpoint configuration, I'm going to assume that this is happening with a file inbound endpoint.

For a reason that goes beyond imagination, the file message receiver behind the inbound endpoint puts the `originalFilename` property in the **outbound** scope when evaluating the expression to generate the archived file name.

So use: `message.outboundProperties.originalFilename`

Comment: I think I understand why that is. Inbound properties would technically be things that affected the way that the adapter worked such as the input directory. However this is an outbound property since it's the result of the adapter's operation.

Answer (score -1):

I have tested this `mel` `EXPRESSION` in `ESB 3.7.1` and it is working fine!!

```
message.inboundProperties.originalFilename=='firstfile.txt'
```

Comment: this is not am amswer. this could be a comment