# how to use value of #[server.dateTime.weekOfYear] in mule-app.properties or configuration xml

Tags: regex, mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-module-jpa

I am downloading files from FTP. I am able to download files with defined patterns or defined name and pass then process these files in Java.

Problem I am facing is that I need to download a new file every week. The file name is like `"constant-prefix-2013-W51.zip"`. My current XML is like this;

```
<ftp:inbound-endpoint 
    host="${ftp.host}" 
    port="${ftp.port}" 
    path="${ftp.pathInbound}" 
    user="${ftp.user}" 
    password="${ftp.password}" 
    responseTimeout="10000" 
    doc:name="KBB_FTP" >

    <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="MyFile-2013-W51.zip"/>

</ftp:inbound-endpoint>
```

> #### Flow Reference: [Mule: How to pass File from FTP to Java class in Mule ESB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657425/mule-how-to-pass-file-from-ftp-to-java-class-in-mule-esb/)

This code downloads the requested file successfully. But I need to add the `year` and `week` value dynamically in file pattern.

I have tried following patterns but no success;

```
 1. pattern="MyFile-2013-W#[server.dateTime.weekOfYear].zip" 

 2. pattern="MyFile-2013-W${server.dateTime.weekOfYear}.zip"
```

I know second pattern is totally wrong as it is not a property which is defined in `.properties` file. I also added a property in mule-app.properties like this

```
 calendar.weekOfYear=#[server.dateTime.weekOfYear]
```

and used following pattern;

```
 3. pattern="MyFile-2013-W${calendar.weekOfYear}.zip"
```

None of this way is working, I want to add year value like `2013` and week value like `51` dynamically which is not happening in any case. Value which appends to fileName is only above string patterns, not any digit..

Answer (score 1):

The `file:filename-wildcard-filter` does not support MEL expressions. Use an `expression-filter` instead, like this:

```
<message-filter throwOnUnaccepted="false">
    <expression-filter
        expression="#[message.outboundProperties.originalFilename == 'MyFile-2013-W'+server.dateTime.weekOfYear+'.zip']" />
</message-filter>
```

Comment: Can you plz explain little more with some code snippet as I am a newbie in mule.. my purpose is to get the file downloaded with a way that fulfills above mentioned requirements..

Comment: I have tried few expressions, but there are errors and exceptions being generated. It will be helpful if you can tell me a line of xml tag to be added in above code..

Comment: Sure, added an example.

Comment: I have replaced my line of code `<file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="MyFile-2013-W51.zip"/>` with your piece of code. But I am getting following error; >>>>> `[Error: could not access: originalFilename; in class: org.mule.el.context.MessagePropertyMapContext]
[Near : {... message.inboundProperties.orig ....}]`

Comment: 2. `Execution of the expression "message.inboundProperties.originalFilename == 'KBBUsedVehiclesNoSpecTabFormat-2013-W'+server.dateTime.weekOfYear+'.zip'" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException)
  org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage:213 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/expression/ExpressionRuntimeException.html)`

Comment: 3. `Execution of the expression "message.inboundProperties.originalFilename == 'KBBUsedVehiclesNoSpecTabFormat-2013-W'+server.dateTime.weekOfYear+'.zip'" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: byte[] (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:35 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
`

Comment: In some transports the properties to be used in an inbound filter happen to be in the outbound scope: maybe it's the case with FTP. Therefore I have changed my answer to use the `outboundProperties` map. I can't test because I don't have an FTP server handy.

Comment: I already tried with outboundProperties, it does not work either. I saw ur answer from here about this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881530/mule-originalfilename-is-null I am getting following Error if I use `outbountProperties`: `Message               : Message has been rejected by filter. Message payload is of type: byte[]
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2`

Comment: `Exception stack is: >>>>> 
1. Message has been rejected by filter. Message payload is of type: byte[] (org.mule.api.routing.filter.FilterUnacceptedException)
  org.mule.routing.MessageFilter:100 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/routing/filter/FilterUnacceptedException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace: >>>>> 
org.mule.api.routing.filter.FilterUnacceptedException: Message has been rejected by filter. Message payload is of type: byte[]`

Comment: Again, I reviewed my proposed answer to try to avoid the `FilterUnacceptedException`. There are so many possible combinations in Mule that it's not always easy to find the right one :$

Comment: Aaaah.... you are right, it is very hard to find help for mule. they have no good documentation and forums.. Again it didn't worked.. This time no files downloaded and no error/exception raised.. It just started the app and nothing more..

Comment: After checking the source code, I understand what's happening. Though the XML config allows any filter to be used, the FTP inbound endpoint only recognizes filters are that are actual implementation of `java.io.FilenameFilter`. And so far I can't locate any Mule-provided `java.io.FilenameFilter` implementation that is MEL-aware :( So you would have to create your own filter to make this work...

Answer (score 0):

Use an expression filter #[server.dateTime.getWeekOfYear()].zip
you can use this expression and customize your time format.